# Table edge effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Photo is attached I need to do this table edge effect with shadows etc.[image]
But how can I do it?

"gray table edge"

Comment: found http://vectips.com/tutorials/3d-vector-text-effect/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is asking for a tutorial. The user is also unlikely to salvage the question, since they commented a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, no worries. 
In case you are using Illustrator.

**Step 1: Apply Gradient Colour 

Step 2: Extrude and Bevel

Step 3: Drop Shadow**

Detailed Process:

**Step One - Apply Correct Gradient Colour**
**a.** Draw the table's edge, go to swatches > swatch libraries > gradients > metals
**b.** Choose the silver or stainless steel gradient and make colour adjustments.

[image: Color Gradient - Steel Edge]

**Step Two - Extrude and Bevel** 
**a.** Selecting your edge, go to Effect > 3D > Extrude and Bevel
**b.** Position: Front, Bevel: Cope, Bevel: Extent Out, Surface: Plastic Shading
**c.** Adjust Colours as required.

[image: 3D Edge Effect]

**Step Three - Drop Shadow**
**a.** Effect > Stylize > Drop-shadow
**b.** Make Adjustments

[image: Applying Drop Shadow]

That's all. Hopefully, you got the technique.

Sorry for not applying 100% same colours, and shadow; the main purpose was to guide you with the technique.

Good luck :)

Comment: not exact same but thanks